# installing latest version of gcc in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, gcc

I installed build_essential on Ubuntu 20.04 and it installed GCC version 9.x
But the latest version of GCC is 11.x.

How can I install the latest version of gcc into Ubuntu 20.04?

I already tried these commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

but I am still having the same version of gcc.

Comment: The first results of a simple Google search for installing gcc-11 on Ubuntu 20.04 will give you what you need.